# Add a a new line in rich text box?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

So, I'm trying to create a terminal of sort in C#. I've chosen a rich text box for the "shell" area and basically every time the user presses enter I add a symbol for the meantime. The problem is, however, that the cursor instead of being ahead of the symbol is on a new line. Here is the simple code:

```
terminal.AppendText("\n>");
```

So, basically, if space here is `|` then what I want is:

```
> |
```

but what I get is this:

```
>
|
```

I know this could have to do with the broader problem of how to add a new line when enter is pressed. What more is needed here?

**Edit:** The full code

```
if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) 
{
   AddLine();
}
```

where `AddLine()` is:

```
private void AddLine() 
{
   terminal.AppendText("\n>");
}
```

**Reminder:** `terminal` is a rich text box in my windows form application. Also, the conditional statement is on the `KeyDown()` method of the rich text box.

Comment: Do you mean something like in the animation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51682585/7444103)? The `Enter Command` control is a RTB.

Comment: @Jimi How can that help me? Please explain....

Comment: `every time the user presses enter`  You have to suppress that key press.  Show us the full code stub.

Comment: @LarsTech I edited my post.

Comment: Well, you can preserve some space, using the `SelectionIndent` property and add a symbol that cannot be *touched* by a User *intervention*, since it's positioned in the inaccessible area created by the property.

Comment: @Jimi I really can't understand what you are saying. Maybe because I never heard of the `SelectionIndent`. Can you post a answer where you explain how to do it? Thanks :)

Comment: Add `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;` above your  `terminal.AppendText("\n>");` line.

Comment: @LarsTech Oh it really works. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the enter key from processing its action on the Text box.  Try adding `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;` to your code:

```
private void Terminal_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    terminal.AppendText("\n>");
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a follow-up question, if I want to prevent the user from deleting the `>` symbol, do I use the same `SuppressKeyPress` method with `Keys.Backspace`?

Comment: @GauravMall That's a little more complicated.  The RichTextBox has a SelectionProtected property that will "protect" a highlighted range of text.

Comment: Okay will check it out. Thanks!

Comment: @GauravMall See [In a textbox, protect the first words, but allow adding/editing to text past those words](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9880291/719186) for an example.

Comment: Your the best! Thanks very much :)